# Reducing HTTP request when using CSS3 media queries

Tags: html, css, media, httprequest

I'm trying to use the CSS3 media query techniques discussed here...

http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries

If I grab the code from below and run it on a new page using some sort of emulator that identifies itself as a device with a small screen (e.g. Device Central or Protofluid) I can see in Charles that a request is still made for each CSS file even though the correct stylsheet is picked up, is this normal behaviour?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="smartphone.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="smartphone-landscape.css" media="only screen and (min-width : 321px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="smartphone-portrait.css" media="only screen and (max-width : 320px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad-landscape.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad-portrait.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="widescreen.css" media="only screen and (min-width : 1824px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="iphone4.css" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, any stylesheets in a link element will be downloaded and the media queries evaluated dynamically.  For instance your stylesheets `ipad-landscape.css` and `ipad-portrait.css` would need to be applied when someone turns their device round, you don't want to wait until they do that to start downloading the stylesheet and any referenced items, it should be ready right away.  The only exception is (or could be) alternate stylesheets.

The processing model for this is [discussed in the HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#link-type-stylesheet):

> The appropriate time to obtain the
>   resource is when the external resource
>   link is created or when its element is
>   inserted into a document, whichever
>   happens last. If the resource is an
>   alternative stylesheet then the user
>   agent may defer obtaining the resource
>   until it is part of the preferred
>   style sheet set.

Comment: Would you therefore recommend serving up a single CSS file, "media-queries.css", and use media query blocks within that, instead of multiple link elements?

Comment: @Danjah That's not really the same question - all this answer is saying is that all the CSS will be downloaded either way

Comment: I suppose so, my question is related to reducing http requests as much as "is there a need to".

Comment: @Danjah So ask a question and stop commenting on this one ;)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome advice, to remind you, this question is entitled: "Reducing HTTP request when using CSS3 media queries". Good heavens, what ever happened to clarification (that's rhetorical, no need to answer that one).

Comment: @Danjah That's what the title is, what the question is about is why the user agent downloads stylesheets even though they don't match the media queries.